# How to get the dictionaries count from the plist file

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I have facing some issue with retrieving data from plist file.actually my plist file is look like this

key             Type         value
Genesis         Dictionary   (0 items)
Exodus          Dictionary   (0 items) 
Leviticus       Dictionary   (0 items)

here how can i retrieve the count of dictionaries in the plist file that is i want the output for this is 3.

if anyBody know this please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, would be appreciated if you actually accept answers to your questions.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = ....
int count = [[dictionary allKeys] count]; // Will return 3. allKeys will contain (Genesis,Exodus,Leviticus)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your plist returns dictionary or array, then in order to know how many dictionary your plist contain you can use count message on your dictionary object.

Comment: a plist can also represent an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourResource" ofType:@"plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) 
{
    NSLog(@"The file exists");
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"The file does not exist");
}

NSMutableDictionary *myDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
int count = [myDic count];
NSLog(@"%d",count);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
NSArray *myPlistPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [myPlistPath objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *myPath = [documentsDirectory
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MYPLIST.plist"]; 
NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath]; 

NSArray *array = [[plistDictionary objectForKey:0]
                      sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]; 

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d MyPlist", [plistDictionary count]];
```